# Is possible to pull a variable from an event in google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

does anyone know if it is possible to pull a variable from an event?
For example, we have 2 different events:

- user_type_id
- customer_type_id

they both have a DL called customer_type, which pulls different information, the user_type_id pulls if a customer is Platinum, while the customer_type_id pulls if it is a Returning customer, however when using customer_type as the variable in GTM, it sometimes pull Platinum and other times it pulls Returning, is there a way i can setup a variable in GTM so that it pulls customer_type FROM the customer_type_id only?

Any help will be appreciated! :) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN3U0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO7mI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The dataLayer is built up of key-value pairs. The key is unique, and if there are multiple calls setting it, you are always replacing the value of the same key.

In your example, there is a key `customer_type` that is being set in two different scenarios. They are both referring to the same key.

You will need to ensure your key names are unique. I would suggest:

- `customer_tier`: platinum, gold, silver, etc.
- `customer_type`: NEW, RETURNING